# Mathematica not finding trivial solution with NSolve

Tags: equation-solving

Mathematica is unable to find the trivial solution to a system of equations.  Why?  And how can you fix this?  See the example below

```
NSolve[{0.5 a - 0.1 d - 0.5 f d - 0.05 d b - 0.05 d c == 0, 
    -0.05 f + 0.3 a + 0.1 d + 0.5 f d + 0.03 b + 0.05 d b + 
    0.2 a (0.5 f + 0.05 b + 0.05 c) + 0.01 c + 0.05 d c == 0, 
    0.0125 f - 0.13 b == 0, 
    0.0375 f - 0.11 c == 0, 
    -0.8 a + 0.1 b - 0.2 a (0.5 f + 0.05 b + 0.05 c) + 0.1 c == 0}, 
 {d, f, b, c, a}, Reals]
```

returns the solutions

```
{{d -> -0.557011, f -> -8.40212, b -> -0.807896, c -> -2.86436, 
  a -> 4.77322}, {d -> 0.034582, f -> 3.30048, b -> 0.317354, 
  c -> 1.12516, a -> 0.126042}, {d -> 1.11643, f -> -0.201318, 
  b -> -0.0193575, c -> -0.0686313, a -> -0.0112953}}
```

which is all well and good, but totally missed the solution `a=b=c=d=f=0`.

I don't understand why mathematica is not returning the trivial solution, are there some options I need to specify for it to find the trivial solution?

Solve can sort of find the trivial solution (but not any others).

`Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>`

```
{{d -> 0, f -> 0., b -> 0, c -> 0, a -> 0}}
```

Comment: Its a method problem try Method -> {"UseSlicingHyperplanes" -> False}

Comment: `NSolve` also warns you "`NSolve::infsolns`: Infinite solution set has dimension at least 1. Returning intersection of solutions with `(153196 a)/195501-(41688 b)/65167-(153968 c)/195501+(185938 d)/195501+(38650 f)/65167 == 1`," which pretty much explains it.  It should not be unexpected since you have five equations and six unknowns.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - there are only 5 unknowns, a b c d f., however I'll check through for independence.

Comment: Thanks @cyrille.piatecki - that found me the trivial solutions (but no others).  Feeling more comfortable with using this approach since it can find what I know to be true.  Now to generalise to the problem I really need to solve ...

Comment: @Esme_ Oops, yep, 5 unknowns.  I must've inserted a `e` manually..  Sorry about that.

Comment: @Esme_ Something like `Reduce[Rationalize@eqns, {d}]` reduces the system to 4 equations and free variable, and some conditions. You can control the choice of free variable with the list `{d}` -- e.g., `{b, f, a, d}` will make `c`.  The order of the list controls the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

```
eq = SetPrecision[
{0.5 a - 0.1 d - 0.5 f d - 0.05 d b - 0.05 d c == 0, 
-0.05 f + 0.3 a + 0.1 d + 0.5 f d + 0.03 b + 0.05 d b + 
          0.2 a (0.5 f + 0.05 b + 0.05 c) + 0.01 c + 0.05 d c == 0, 
0.0125 f - 0.13 b == 0, 
0.0375 f - 0.11 c == 0, 
-0.8 a + 0.1 b - 0.2 a (0.5 f + 0.05 b + 0.05 c) + 0.1 c == 0}, 
30];

sol= NSolve[eq, {d, f, b, c, a}, Reals]
{{d -> -0.0295255572154826154092346605969, 
  f -> -21.3769623310349877877253230598, 
  b -> -2.05547714721490271578201289861, 
  c -> -7.2876007946710182575252163264, 
  a -> 0.65284757118928026344705707724}, 
{d -> 0, f -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0, a -> 0}}

eq /. sol
{{True, True, True, True, True}, {True, True, True, True, True}}
```

This outcome might satisfy, but with `Rationalize`, we get a better overview.

```
 eq2 = Rationalize[
    {0.5 a - 0.1 d - 0.5 f d - 0.05 d b - 0.05 d c == 0, 
    -0.05 f + 0.3 a + 0.1 d + 0.5 f d + 0.03 b + 0.05 d b + 
              0.2 a (0.5 f + 0.05 b + 0.05 c) + 0.01 c + 0.05 d c == 0, 
    0.0125 f - 0.13 b == 0, 
    0.0375 f - 0.11 c == 0, 
    -0.8 a + 0.1 b - 0.2 a (0.5 f + 0.05 b + 0.05 c) + 0.1 c == 0}, 
    0];
sol2 = Solve[eq2, {d, f, b, c, a}, Reals]
```

[image]

"a" is parameter! You have infinity solutions.

```
sol2/. a -> 0
{{d -> 0, f -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0}}

sol2 /. a -> 1
{{d -> -(1735/23533), f -> -(4576/347), b -> -(440/347), c -> -(1560/347)}}
```

and so on!

Answer (score 0):

Your observation is contrary to mine in Mathematica 8. Here NSolve only finds the trivial Null solution. I checked the first solution of yours and it returns false.

```
  {d = -0.557011, f = -8.40212, b = -0.807896, c = -2.86436, 
 a = 4.77322}
 0.5 a - 0.1 d - 0.5 f d - 0.05 d b - 0.05 d c == 0
    False
```

Curious...

Comment: Note that it's rare that plugging in a machine-precision solution into an equation of the form `lhs == 0` returns `True`, because of rounding error. E.g. `x^2 - 2 == 0 /. x -> Sqrt[2.]`.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelE2 I wasn't aware of this. With rewi answer it becomes even more clear and I got the same result.